# Viewcontroller crashes after being presented by another viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift

For some reason, `viewDidLoad()` crashes with

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

in `authViewController` in my app while setting up the UI after it's being presented from another viewcontroller:

```
//authViewController
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        authState.addTarget(self, action: #selector(authStateChanged), for: .valueChanged)//<-- The place where it crashes

        emailInput.addTarget(self, action: #selector(emailPasswordTextChanged), for: .editingChanged)
        passwordInput.addTarget(self, action: #selector(emailPasswordTextChanged), for: .editingChanged)
        SignIn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(signInPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        //Set actions

        infoView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        SignIn.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        //UI setup
}
```

The Other View Controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        FIRAuth.auth()?.addStateDidChangeListener({ (auth, user) in
            if user != nil {

            }
            else {
                print("pop")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.present(authViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

Can anybody please tell me what and why it happened if you know?

Comment: You can't present viewController like this self.present(authViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)

Try presenting viewController after instantiating it

Comment: It worked, thanks!

Comment: Without intializing viewcontroller you can't present it. First intialize it then call present view controller, thats why it is found nil and crashed the app.

Comment: @Sunnyyue ohh that's cool. I haved added that as the answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of presenting the `ViewController` like

```
self.present(authViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Try presenting `ViewController` after instantiating it

```
let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: storyboardname, bundle: nil)
let authVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: viewController Identifier) as? authViewController
self.present(authVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by doing:

```
let authVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "authVC")
self.present(authVC!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```